# Sufficent condition for existence of $1$-basis

Tags: graph-theory

An $1$-basis for a directed graph $D$ is defined as a minimal set of mutually non-adjacent points $S$ such that every point of the graph is either a point of $S$ or adjacent from a point of $S$.

Now, if the graph has no directed odd cycle, then prove that the graph must have a $1$-basis.

Answer (score 1):

Let's show that each [strongly connected](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StronglyConnectedDigraph.html) digraph with no odd cycles has $1$-basis. It is easy to see that base of strong digraph with no directed odd cycle is bipartite graph. Thus we can include into $S$ all vertices from one non-empty part and get $1$-basis.

In general case of digraph with no directed odd cycle we find condensation that is a result of contraction of all strongly connected components. In condensation there always is a vertex of zero indegree, corresponding to some strongly connected component $C$. We take $1$-basis $S_C$ of $C$ and remove from graph each vertex $v$ from $S_C$ together with $N^+(v)$ (that is a set of vertices adjacent from $v$). If there are some vertices remaining then repeat this process.

At the end process gives $1$-basis $S = \bigcup_c S_C$ of initial digraph.